$H^1$ norm in terms of an $L^p$ for $p \neq 2$
There is a claim I came across that the $H^1$ norm can be defined as (for $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded)
$$\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 = \|u\|^{\alpha}_{L^\alpha(\Omega)} +  \|\nabla u\|^{2}_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
for $\alpha \leq 2$. It is weird that it is equality. I thought it (if true) should be inequality, something like
$$\|u\|^{2}_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C  \|u\|^{\alpha}_{L^\alpha(\Omega)} $$
First of all, is the claim correct? If yes, I wonder what is the reasoning behind underlying it? Is it particular embedding theorem (I couldn't find any thing immediate)?

The second claim cannot be true: replace $u$ by $\lambda \cdot u$ with $\lambda>0$. Then check the behavior of lhs and rhs for $\lambda\to0$ and $\to\infty$.

So first, as indicated in the comment by daw, the definition
$$
\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 = \|u\|^{\alpha}_{L^\alpha(\Omega)} +  \|\nabla u\|^{2}_{L^2(\Omega)},
$$
does not give a norm because it is not homogeneous, i.e. it does not verify for any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, $\|\lambda u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} = |\lambda |\,\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$. But this can be fixed easily by defining instead
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
N_\alpha(u)^2 := \|u\|_{L^\alpha(\Omega)}^2 +  \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.
$$
Now the important thing to understand is that in infinite dimensional spaces such as function spaces, what is usually important is the topology, which is independent of the choice of the norm as long as the norm are equivalent. For this reason, the definition of norms for spaces of functions will often be different depending on the reference/application. Anyway, more generally in mathematics, the definitions that are universal are rare and it is good to define objects.
The space $H^1$ is often defined as
$$
H^1(\Omega) := \{f\in L^2(\Omega):\nabla f\in L^2(\Omega)\}
$$
where $\nabla$ denotes the gradient in weak sense (or in the sense of distributions). Then $N_2$ defines a norm on this space. Of course, an expression such as $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} +  \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ would also define a norm equivalent to $N_2$ by equivalence of norms in finite dimension. For any other $\alpha>0$, the fact that $N_\alpha$ satisfies the positivity property, the homogeneity property and the triangle inequality is not difficult to check. It remains to check

if $N_\alpha$ is finite in $H^1$, in which case it could in indeed be used to define a norm on $H^1$.
but as I was indicating, one is often concerned about the topology, and so one could rather prefer to define a norm equivalent to the natural $N_2$ norm.

Bot questions are solved by the following inequalities:

Since $\Omega$ is bounded, by Hölder's inequality for any $\alpha\leq \beta$, there exists $C>0$ such that for any $u$, $\|u\|_{L^\alpha(\Omega)} \leq C \,\|u\|_{L^\beta(\Omega)}$, hence
$$
N_\alpha \leq C_{\alpha,\beta}\, N_\beta.
$$
for some constant $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ depending on $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $|\Omega|$.
On the other hand, by Sobolev inequalities, there exists $C>0$ such that for any $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, $\|u\|_{L^q} \leq C\, N_2(u)$, where $q = 2^* = \frac{2n}{n-2}>2$ if $n>2$ and $q=\infty$ if $n\in\{1,2\}$. Since of course $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \leq N_2(u)$, it follows that
$$
N_q \leq C_{q,2}\,N_2.
$$
for some constant $C_{q,2}$ depending on $n$, and $\Omega$.
Finally, by Hölder's inequality, for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\|u\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{L^q}^\theta \,\|u\|_{L^1}^{1-\theta} \leq \varepsilon\, \|u\|_{L^q} + C_\varepsilon\,\|u\|_{L^1}$ with $\theta\in(0,1)$ such that $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\theta}{q}+1-\theta$ and the second inequality follows from Young's inequality for multiplication. Hence
$$
N_2 \leq \varepsilon \,N_q + C_\varepsilon\,N_1 \leq \varepsilon\,C_{q,2} \,N_2 + C_\varepsilon\,N_1
$$
and so taking for instance $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}\,C_{q,2}^{-1}$, it gives
$$
N_2 \leq C_{2,1} \,N_1
$$
for some constant $C_{2,1}$ depending on $n$ and $\Omega$.
Combining these inequalities, it follows that for any $\alpha\in[1,q]$ (and so in particular if $\alpha<2$, but even for some $\alpha>2$!) $N_2 \leq C_{2,1}\,N_1 \leq C_{2,1}C_{1,\alpha}\, N_\alpha$ and $N_\alpha\leq C_{\alpha,q}\, N_q \leq C_{\alpha,q}C_{q,2}\, N_2$ so
$$
\frac{1}{C_{2,1}C_{1,\alpha}}\,N_2 \leq N_\alpha \leq C_{\alpha,q}C_{q,2}\,N_2.
$$
That is, all the $N_\alpha$ norms are equivalent for all $\alpha\in[1,q]$.

To write $\|u\|_{H^1} := N_\alpha(u)$ for some fixed chosen $\alpha$ is then simply a choice of notation. Of course, it means that $\|u\|_{H^1}$ does not denote $N_2(u)$ if $\alpha\neq 2$.
